# Angular 14 SSR - TypeError: el.removeEventListener is not a function

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

all

We have angular 14 app with SSR, it has been working for long time.

With recent changes made for adding new modules, application gives following error when accessed in browser

NG0406: This instance of the `ApplicationRef` has already been destroyed.
NG0406: This instance of the `ApplicationRef` has already been destroyed.
NG0406: This instance of the `ApplicationRef` has already been destroyed.
TypeError: el.removeEventListener is not a function

And in the Broswer console

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-rsa65p5KwWrQJNSLFJ61XTnhuhYMF923Nkzgcp6zgog='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Best Regards,
Bojja

Tried adding CSP in Index.html
http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"y

Please help on

TypeError: el.removeEventListener is not a function